# Implicit multiplication with Math.NET Infixes

Tags: mathnet-numerics, math.net, mathdotnet-symbolics

Is there a way to force `Infix.ParseOrThrow` and related functions from the [Math.NET Symbolics](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-symbolics) library to allow equations such as "4x + 3" instead of requiring the input to be "4*x + 3"?

Comment: maybe there is ...what have you tried ?

Comment: well, if you really want it you can fork the library and make some change to function for parsing expressions.

Comment: (instead of fork of library you can create your own parser and use it for creating expressions)